# How to get serveral keys value from redis at one time

Tags: php, redis

In my project, I use redis. And i want to fetch several data at one time.

So I choose mget function.

In redis, I have values:

```
 redis> get u_trade_1
 "0"
 redis> smembers st_a_1
 1) "1"
 2) "1500184800"
 3) "1532588400"
 redis> smembers info_g_1
 1) "1"
 2) "100"
 3) "1299"
 4) "1399"
 5) "9970"
```

Now  I define a array for fetching these data at one time.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$redis_obj = \common\Datasource::getRedis('instance1');//connect redis successfully

$d_list = array(
 'u_trade_1',
 'st_a_1',
 'info_g_1',
 'info_g_2',
 'info_g_3'
 );

 $data_list = $redis_obj->mget($d_list);
 echo ($data_list[0]);
```

The correct value of $data_list[0] should be 0, But it works fail. It show nothing.

It seems nothing wrong, Who can give me a favor?

Comment: @NigelRen, Yes , I made a mistake, see my update

Comment: `MGET` only works on keys of `STRING` type. It doesn't work on `SET`

Comment: @for_stack, maybe. But do you have a way to deal with this problem?